# How to remove links from tweets (proper)?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I got this:

```
def non_ascii(s):
    return "".join(i for i in s if ord(i)<128)

def lower(text):
    return text.lower()

def clean_links(text):
    txt = re.compile('http[s]{1}://[\w+][.]{1}[\w+][.]{1}[\w]{2,3}')
    return txt.sub(r'', text)

def clean_html(text):
    html = re.compile('<.*?>')
    return html.sub(r'', text)

def punct(text):
    token = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    text = token.tokenize(text)
    text = " ".join(text)
    return text
```

Then later I call these functions like:

```
data['cleaned'] = data['tweet'].apply(non_ascii)
data['cleaned'] = data['tweet'].apply(lower)
data['cleaned'] = data['tweet'].apply(clean_links)
data['cleaned'] = data['tweet'].apply(clean_html)
data['cleaned'] = data['tweet'].apply(punct)
```

The problem is that any link **still** is in the data['cleaned'] column, I need those pesky links erased!

The original tweets are in data['tweet'].

Please add your support, or your way of doing this "**removing links**".

Links still in the data look like:

```
https t co OR1IkVzzgO
```

Comment: You can fin [other suggestions for regex to use to match URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url) Can you give an example of links that are still present in the dataset (i.e. that are not replaced by your regex)?

Comment: Maybe these links are HTML tags (`<a href="....">`)? If so, you have to remove the whole tag instead of just the URL. Can you include some examples of tweets before and after removal (tweet and cleaned column)?

Comment: The issue is that you don't method chain. You continuously overwrite your previous results of your function calls.  Your entire block of function calls is functionally only equivalent to `data['tweet'].apply(punct)` because you don't use the results of your previous function call as input for your next function call.

Comment: second function (and next functions) you should run on `data['cleaned'].apply(...)` . OR you should chain it `data['tweet'].apply(non_ascii).apply(...).apply(...)`. OR you should create one function with `non_ascii`, `lower`, etc and use only one `.apply()`

Comment: BTW: instead of `text.lower()` you can use `str.lower(text)` - and then you don't need own function `lower()`

Comment: your regex doesn't match to links - better works even `'http(s)?://\w+(\.\w+){1,}(/\w+)*(/)?'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second function (and next functions) you have to run on `data['cleaned']`

```
data['cleaned'] = data['tweet'].apply(non_ascii)
data['cleaned'] = data['cleaned'].apply(lower)
data['cleaned'] = data['cleaned'].apply(clean_links)
data['cleaned'] = data['cleaned'].apply(clean_html)
data['cleaned'] = data['cleaned'].apply(punct)
```

OR you should chain it

```
data['cleaned'] = data['tweet'].apply(non_ascii).apply(lower).apply(clean_links).apply(clean_html).apply(punct)
```

OR you should put all functions in one function and run `apply()` only once

```
def clean(text):
    text = non_ascii(text)
    text = lower(text)
    text = clean_links(text)
    text = clean_html(text)
    text = punct(text)
    return text

data['cleaned'] = data['tweet'].apply(clean)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Instead of `text.lower()` you can use `str.lower(text)` and you don't have to create own function `lower()`

Your regex doesn't match to links so I used something little better `'http(s)?://\w+(\.\w+){1,}(/\w+)*'` - but it may not work with more complex links and you should use regex suggested in comments.

Stackoverflow doesn't allow to use `https:// t.co/ OR1IkVzzgO` in code  so you have to remove spaces from link.

---

Minimal working code with example data

```
import re
import nltk.tokenize
import pandas as pd

def non_ascii(s):
    return "".join(i for i in s if ord(i)<128)

def clean_links(text):
    txt = re.compile('http(s)?://\w+(\.\w+){1,}(/\w+)*')
    return txt.sub(r'', text)

def clean_html(text):
    html = re.compile('<.*?>')
    return html.sub(r'', text)

def punct(text):
    token = nltk.tokenize.RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    text = token.tokenize(text)
    text = " ".join(text)
    return text

def clean(text):
    text = non_ascii(text)
    text = str.lower(text)
    text = clean_links(text)
    text = clean_html(text)
    text = punct(text)
    return text

# --- main ---

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'tweet': ['Example https://stackoverflow.com/ 
. And <tag>other</tag> line https:// t.co/ OR1IkVzzgO. Any question?']
})

data['cleaned'] = data['tweet'].apply(clean)

print(data.to_string())
```

---

**EDIT:**

More universal version which gets list of functions

```
def clean(text, *functions):
    for func in functions:
        text = func(text)
    return text

data['cleaned'] = data['tweet'].apply(clean, args=[non_ascii, str.lower, clean_links, clean_html, punct])
```